# How to make content full width for print stylesheet after hiding left nav bar

Tags: html, css

In creating a print stylesheet, I want to hide all the navigation but since the site has a left nav-bar that extends the full height of the window, how can I have the content that is printed take up the full width of the page? Currently, the content will display and print fine but there is a "column" on the page where the nav-bar use to be.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    .column {
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    .clearfix::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }
    
    .menu {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #e9e9e9;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 25%;
    }
    
    .content {
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 25%;
      padding-left: 60px;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    .menu ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .menu li {
      padding: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      background-color: #33b5e5;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .menu li:hover {
      background-color: #0099cc;
    }
    
    @media print {
      .menu {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="column menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Nav Item</li>
        <li>Nav Item</li>
        <li>Nav Item</li>
        <li>Nav Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="column content">
      <h1>Title / Heading</h1>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
      <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting `display: none` on the `.menu`, you'll also want to 'reset' the `margin-left` and `padding-left` of the `.content` back to `0` inside of your `@media print`:

```
@media print {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .content {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    .column {
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    .clearfix::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }
    
    .menu {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #e9e9e9;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 25%;
    }
    
    .content {
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 25%;
      padding-left: 60px;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    .menu ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .menu li {
      padding: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      background-color: #33b5e5;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .menu li:hover {
      background-color: #0099cc;
    }
    
    @media print {
      .menu {
        display: none;
      }
      .content {
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="column menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Nav Item</li>
        <li>Nav Item</li>
        <li>Nav Item</li>
        <li>Nav Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="column content">
      <h1>Title / Heading</h1>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
      <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```